# Jquery class selector click repeat function

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, selector

I have a class selector with a click binded. Problem happens when I click more than one time, it recalls the function two times at the first, three times at the next click and so on.

```
var point = data.points[0].x;
    var counter = 0;          
    $(".menuOption").click(function () {
        console.log(counter);
        counter++;    
        var code = $(this).attr('id');
        var text = $(this).html();
        var newLine = {
            type: 'line',
            x0: point,
            x1: point,
            y0: 0,
            y1: 1,
            yref: 'paper',
            line: {
                color: 'black',
                width: 1
            },
            name: text
        };
        var annotation = {
            x: point,
            y: data.points[0].y,
            xref: 'x',
            yref: 'y',
            text: code,
            textangle: 90,
            showarrow: true,
            arrowhead: 7
        }
        Plotly.relayout("grap", {
            'shapes[0]': newLine,
            'hovermode': 'closest',
            'annotations[0]': annotation
        });

    });
```

I added some console.log in the pen below.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/dmance/pen/mMdXqG)

Comment: place unbind before it like, $(".menuOption").unbind();

Comment: It worked a bit... It still repeats the function. I'm using a handler by plot-ly, maybe it has some differences. Actually i dont know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 76, you're setting up a click listener:

```
myPlot.on('plotly_click', function (data) { ... }
```

Inside that handler (line 106), you are setting up another click listener on the menu option:

```
$(".menuOption").click(function () { ... }
```

So every time the `plotly_click` event happens, you are adding another click listener. You should likely move the binding of the menuOption click listener outside of the event handler, or you should unbind the listener before setting up a new one.

Comment: Ooh, thanks. It makes sense, i made an if inside and solved the problem but it is not the correct solution.